# Can't reference with useRef a file with an input file tag in react

Tags: reactjs, file, react-hooks, reactstrap

I am using reacstrap and react-hooks-form and I have:

```
                      <Input
                        type="file"
                        innerRef={refPhoto}
                        name="photo"
                        onChange={removeFile()}
                      />
```

Then onSubmit I have:

```
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    return isCreateMode
        ? createProduct(data)
        : updateProduct(data);
  } 



  const createProduct = dataRegister => {  
    const config = {
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
   }
  
   setLoading(true)
   const product = new FormData();
   product.append('photo', refPhoto.current.files[0]);
   product.append('hotel_id', selectedHotel);
```

I declare refPhoto as:

```
  const notifyEl = useRef(null);
```

But I am getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null
```

I have tried passing useRef as an argument, just in case it was given `createProduct` was stored as a closure, but it does not work either.

Comment: please try to understand Forwarding Refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: Am I forwarding the ref by using "innerRef"?  I don't know how to use that information to solve my issue